# is there any way in vim to apply even spacing for variable declaration?

Tags: vim

Let say I have something like this:

```
int foo()
{
    int temp;
    char **argv;
    uint32_t test;
}
```

is there any key or a squence of commands to have above lines turned into something like:

```
int foo()
{
    int      temp;
    char     **argv;
    uint32_t test;
}
```

I am using space as tab if that matters.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother. If you add or delete a variable you may need to reformat the surrounding declarations which will make the diff unnecessarily big. Lining up variables this way also won't work with a proportional font. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using Tabular plugin. There is great vimcast covering that subject: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Comment: just tried the link and installed plugin. works like a charm!!! it's beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a macro with following keystrokes (I saved it under register `w` ):

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>`$vT da` <kbd>space</kbd>*10 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> `:s/\%17c\s*//` <kbd>enter</kbd> `j` <kbd>q</kbd>

This is what was saved in register `w`:

```
$vT da          ^C^Cp:s/\%17c\s*//^Mj
```

- `$` - go to end of line
- `vT` - mark everything until space using previous search with T
- `d` - delete what was marked
- `a          ^C` - insert spaces ( as much as you want )
- `p` - paste what you've previously deleted
- `s/\%17c\s*//` - delete whitespaces starting from 17th column
- `j` - go to the line below

Amount of spaces and column number may be different for you.

It isn't as easy as installing plugin, but I think it is more fun to write your own macro, using it and seeing that it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) plugin.

In your case, all I need to do is select the 3 lines, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

(Enter triggers interactive mode, <kbd>-</kbd> means `last` and <kbd>Space</kbd> is space. I.e. "Align on last space character"

The plugin is really useful and it's really easy to just make up new alignment rules on the fly.